# Want to find "twenty-two" but returns "twenty" in Python regex.finditer

Tags: python, regex

My purpose is to find out all age related words in a document. As an example, in the sentence "She's twenty-two. And she's loving you. And you'll never know how it makes me blue", I would like to find twenty-two. But regex.finditer always returns twenty instead of twenty-two.

```
enter code here

regex_list = {}

regex_list['before_age'] = (r'age|aged|he\s*is|she\s*is|she\'s|he\'s')

regex_list["nums_as_words"] = (r'two|twenty|twenty-two')

p = r'(?i)(({before_age})\s*[a\s|an\s]?\s*({number_words}))'.format(
    before_age = regex_list['before_age'],
    number_words = regex_list["nums_as_words"]
    )

text = "She's twenty-two. And she's loving you. And you'll never know how it makes me blue"

for match in regex.finditer(p, str(text)):
    if match.group(3):
        print (match.group(3))
```

Returns:
twenty

Comment: Try to put twent-two before twenty in you num as words

Answer (score 1):

The order of the regex matters.

Try

```
regex_list["nums_as_words"] = (r'two|twenty-two|twenty')
```

Since twenty is inside twenty-two, it always found that first.